# wxPython - SetBitmap results in repositioning and double image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, wxpython

I want to update an Image of my [`wx.StaticBitmap`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.StaticBitmap.html?highlight=wx.static#wx.StaticBitmap) when the mouse is over the widget. Baiscally, switch to Black and White for testing.

My problem is that when `self.image.SetBitmap(...)` is called, the image repositions in my window and also the old one stays on the old position.

Additional question: Is it possible to make my Image Black and White without loading a new BW Image?

Here is my code:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.png = wx.Bitmap("TestButton.png")
        self.png_bw = wx.Bitmap("TestButton_bw.png")

        self.image = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, 1, self.png)

        self.image.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnOver)
        self.image.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeave)

        hbox.Add(self.image,1)        

        self.panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.SetTitle('Button Test')
        self.Centre()

    def OnOver(self, event):
        self.image.SetBitmap(self.png_bw)
    def OnLeave(self, event):
        self.image.SetBitmap(self.png)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.panel.Layout()` to force it to arrange items

```
def OnOver(self, event):
    self.image.SetBitmap(self.png_bw)
    self.panel.Layout()

def OnLeave(self, event):
    self.image.SetBitmap(self.png)
    self.panel.Layout()
```

---

On Linux I had to bind events to `self.panel` instead of `self.image`

```
    self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnOver)
    self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeave)
```

If `self.image.Bind()` works on your system then don't change it.
Maybe it only problem on Linux.

---

Using this I can put item in center of window

```
    hbox.Add(self.image, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
```

---

Using `wx.Image()` you can load image and it has methods to convert to greyscale.

```
    img = wx.Image("TestButton.png")
    img_bw = img.ConvertToGreyscale(0.3, 0.3, 0.3)

    self.png = wx.Bitmap(img)
    self.png_bw = wx.Bitmap(img_bw)
```

Doc: [wx.Image](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html)

Comment: If i do it with `self.panel.Layout()` i have the problem that the bindings "fire" if the mouse enters and leaves the WIndow not the StaticBitmap.

Comment: as I said on Linux I had to use `self.panel.Bind()` because `self.image.Bind()` doesn't fire events. But if `self.image.Bind()` works on your system then keep it.

Comment: I used only `self.panel.Layout()` not `self.panel.Bind()`, because i am on an windows  os!

Comment: it can be different situation - static image may use full space in panel even if bitmap is smaller then panel and you see margins around image. I can see this problem when I use `self.image = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel, 1, self.png)` and set its background color `self.image.SetBackgroundColour((255,0,0))`.

Comment: `hbox.Add(self.image,-1)` did the trick with positioning. Center the widget also worked! Thank you!